# KeyError: 'next_max_id' - Instagram API

Tags: python, instagram-api

This script prints a CSV of all geolocated Instagram photos with a certain tag between dates.  Retrieved directly from here...https://gist.github.com/mapmeld/4161980.  I know there has been some recent changes to the instagram api. What does this error mean and how can I resolve?

```
import json
import urllib
import datetime

createdate = datetime.datetime.now()
latestprint = datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 11) # Nov 11, 2012
earliestprint = datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 28) # Oct 28, 2012

client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
access_token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


max_id = ""
tagname = "wtamu"
csvout = open('wtamu.csv', 'w')

print "ID, CREATED_TIME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, INSTAGRAM URL, PHOTO URL"
csvout.write("ID,CREATED_TIME,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,INSTAGRAM_URL,PHOTO_URL\n")

while(createdate > earliestprint):
    apiout = urllib.urlopen("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + tagname + "/media/recent?max_id=" + max_id + "&access_token=" + access_token).read()

    photopage = None
    try:
        photopage = json.loads( apiout )
    except:
        print apiout
        continue

    photos = photopage["data"]

    for photo in photos:
        createdate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(photo["created_time"]) )
        #print createdate
        if(createdate < latestprint and createdate > earliestprint):
            # inside timestamp bounds
            if((photo.has_key("location") == True) and (photo["location"] is not None) and (photo["location"].has_key("latitude") == True)):

                # has a location
                latitude = str(photo["location"]["latitude"])
                longitude = str(photo["location"]["longitude"])

                # print out CSV format
                print "\"" + (photo["id"] or "") + "\"," + (photo["created_time"] or "") + "000," + latitude + "," + longitude + ",\"" + (photo["link"] or "") + "\",\"" + (photo["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]  or "") + "\""
                csvout.write("\"" + (photo["id"] or "") + "\"," + (photo["created_time"] or "") + "000," + latitude + "," + longitude + ",\"" + (photo["link"] or "") + "\",\"" + (photo["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]  or "") + "\"\n")

    max_id = photopage["pagination"]["next_max_id"]
    print "max_id = " + max_id
    createdate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( int( int( max_id ) / 1000 ) )
```